# Android Wifi P2P connection is not created

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have two devices: HTC One X (Android 4.2.2) and Samsung Note N8000 (Android 4.1.2)

I need to connect them using Wifi P2P.

I taken an example from [Creating P2P Connections with Wi-Fi](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html), created broadcast receiver and Wifi P2P initializion.

```
private class WifiP2PBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public WifiP2PBroadcastReceiver() {
        register();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);

            logger.fine("WifiP2PBroadcastReceiver: WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION " + ((state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
        }
        else if (action.equals(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            peersUpdated();
        }
    }

    public void register() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);

        context.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);
    }

    public void unregister() {
        context.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
}
```

Wifi P2P initialization:

```
private void initWifiP2p() {
// initialization 
wifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);

channel = wifiP2pManager.initialize(context, context.getMainLooper(), new WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChannelDisconnected() {
            logger.fine("onChannelDisconnected");
        }
    });

// peer disccovery
wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            peersUpdated();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
        }
    });
}

// method called when discoverPeers listener's onSuccess is called
private void peersUpdated() {
    logger.fine("peersUpdated");

    wifiP2pManager.requestPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
            // print all peers
            for (WifiP2pDevice device : peers.getDeviceList()) {
                logger.fine("peersUpdated: " + device.deviceName + " " + device.primaryDeviceType + " " + device.deviceAddress);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

On both devices: if Wifi AP is disconnected - nothing happens, no Wifi connection is initiated. Broadcast receiver onReceive with action WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION is not called.
What i need to do to establish Wifi P2P connection?

If devices are connected to Wifi AP, WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION is called, but no peers are found.

Answer (score 5):

I found that both of my devices two nexus 4 running KitKat, needed to call discoverPeers.
To first of all 'discover' each other.

Then I have to in the onReceive in your BroadCastReceive class, hook into this message:

```
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))
```

then call

```
if (mManager != null) {
    mManager.requestPeers(mChannel,mMyWiFiActivity );
}
```

This will then trigger the onPeerAvailable, in which ever class you have set up your PeerListListener in.

Once your devices 'know' about each other then the `(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))` event seems to happen.
and I put a call in there as well for requestPeers.

I'm just at the early stages of my developing, and having the call to request peers is two places doesn't seem right, but at the moment I'm going with it. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks! I was also facing the issue where WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION intent would never fire. I was missing the call to discoverPeers for the receiving device. Once, I called discoverPeers on sending and receiving device (after initialise), it triggered WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION action.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following **Permission in Manifest** file

```
<uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: These permissions are set in AndroidManifest.xml.